# Searching for specific keywords in text Python

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, keyword

Lets say without regex I want to print a line in some text containing 3 words but can't have one word... I assume it'd look something like this:

In this example, let body be a collection of text

```
keyword1 = 'blue'
keyword2 = 'bunny'
keyword3 = 'fluffy'
badkeyword = 'rabies'
for link in links:
    text = str(body)
    if keyword1 in text and keyword2 in text and keyword3 in text and badkeyword not in text:
        print("found line")
        print(line)
```

I would want this to print the line with "blue" "bunny" and "fluffy" but if that line happened to have "rabies" in it, skip it.

Comment: And what's the *problem* with the code you currently have?

Comment: Your line should have all among `"blue" "bunny" and "fluffy"` or just any of these?

Comment: Then you need to investigate those *"few different things"* and figure out where the problem is (or if you actually have one) - see e.g. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri yes, all of those keywords need to be present in the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simplify your `if` condition using [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
keywords = (keyword1, keyword2, keyword3)
if all(word in text for word in keywords) and badkeyword not in text:
    # Do something
```